# Thumbnail doesn't appear for Flickr ECL Components

Tags: web8, ecl

I was trying to implement Flickr ECL, using [extension](http://www.sdltridionworld.com/community/2011_extensions/flickr_ecl_provider.aspx) and configured in my Tridion.

Images and Albums are reflecting in Tridion,  but thumbnail images are not working properly, I see a blank image.

**On Folder View**

[image]

**ECL Component View**

[image]

I have debug on `GetThumbnailImage` method it is working fine, cleared cache many times but still I was getting blank.

**Update:**

I tried to inspect `img(blank)` in Component view, it was pointing to `http://localhost/WebUI/Editors/Base/icon.png?target=view&maxwidth=320&maxheight=200&uri=ecl%3A9-flickr-38587920765_b15971826b_72157690242528371-img-file&modified=20180104062538&state=ecl%3AFile.L0P0`

**GetThumbnailImage code**

```
public byte[] GetThumbnailImage(IEclUri eclUri, int maxWidth, int maxHeight)
{
    // only return thumbnails for the actual photos
    if (eclUri.ItemType == EclItemTypes.File && eclUri.SubType == "img")
    {
        // format of photo item id: [flickr photo id]_[flickr photo secret]_[flickr photo set id]
        string[] ids = eclUri.ItemId.Split('_');
        FlickrInfo photo = Provider.Flickr.GetPhotoInfo(ids[0], ids[1], ids[2]);

        WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
        byte[] thumbnailData = webClient.DownloadData(Flickr.GetPhotoUrl(photo, maxWidth));
        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(thumbnailData, false))
        {
            return Provider.HostServices.CreateThumbnailImage(maxWidth, maxHeight, ms, Flickr.MaxWidth, Flickr.MaxHeight, null);
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: I added a link to my Flickr ECL repository (assuming you are talking about that, if not, please **edit** and update to the one you are talking about). Can you **edit** your question and tag the version of Tridion you are using, that might be beneficial for getting correct answers. Also you mention everything is working fine, does that mean when you publish you are getting the Flickr image on your website correctly?

Comment: Hi Bart, I havent published anything yet, am at very initial stage of importing from flickr . I have edited my question

Comment: If you can, please provide code snippet of `GetThumbnailImage(IEclUri eclUri, int maxWidth, int maxHeight)` method? I think your implementation of `CreateThumbnailImage()` is not returning correct bytes of thumbnails. I guess if you debug the code on these you will get to know what you are missing.

Comment: If you are debugging does `Flickr.GetPhotoUrl(photo, maxWidth)` (line 111 of https://github.com/bkoopman/sdl-tridion-world/blob/master/Flickr%20ECL%20Provider/trunk/Flickr%20ECL%20Provider/Mountpoint.cs#L111) return a visible URL of a photo?

Comment: Yeah I was able to get the URL. When I hover on the blank image ,a mouse clickable is getting enabled, when i click on then it taking me to farm url of Flickr

Comment: Did you try yuriy's suggestion of installing microsoft's fix for this issue? If long as you do not ensure windows is fixed you should not expect this to be resolved.

Comment: It will be helpful to confirm if Windows updates (including KB4043769) have been installed on this server.  Also, can try deploying another ECL extension to verify if the thumbnail issue also happens in the other extension.  If so, it may well be a network/platform issue as opposed to an ECL configuration issue.

Comment: @TerryKim , KB4043769 patch  up wouldnt work well , still we're getting blank  images

Comment: I tried to Check whether it is working on sample Aspx page , Images are displaying correctly.

Comment: KB4043769 patch up worked thanks @TerryKim

Answer (score 4):

I want to start by saying that this doesn't have to be only code/tridion issue.
For example, we had similar issue with our thumbnail icons where they weren't downloaded also from media manager.
In our case, we observed that thumbnails aren't downloaded even with correct connection to Media Manager.
We were debugging this for days with SDL customer support, only to find out that there was firewall issue. :) 
Some of the traffic was blocked by firewall, so thumbnails weren't downloaded in correct folder in tridion.
So please try to investigate with Infra team if there is some network blockage. This might fix the problem.